# determine the sets of the following points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

can you guys help me check my work, thanks

Determine expressions for the following sets

a) the sets of points equidistant from $Q(2,0,0)$ and the $zy$ plane?

b)The set of points $X$ such that the triangle formed by $P(4, 0, 0), Q(−1, 0, 0)$, and $X(x, y, z)$ has a right angle at $X$. (Hint: Does the set contain $P$? Does it contain $Q$?)

Attempt:
a)

$(x-2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 0$

b) i dont know to start that

Comment: For b), it's well known that the solution is the sphere having the line $PQ$ as diameter. Has the solution to use analytical methods? the very old idea solving it is the relation between inscribed angle and central angle for a circle.

Comment: a) is the definition of a paraboloid of revolution.

Comment: Um... what you wrote for a) is only the point (2,0,0).

Comment: a) distance of (x,y,z) from (2,0,0) is $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.  Distance from $(x,y,z) $ to zy plane is $|x|$ so you you $\sqrt{(x-2)^2 + y^2 + z^2}= |x|$.  Or $(x-2)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for b)

Write $\vec{PX}$ and $\vec{QX}$ and consider their dot product.